# Convert milliseconds to years

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a validator that checks if an user is at least 18 years old.

This is the check:

```
var res = /^([1-2]\d{3})\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\-([0-9]{4})$/.exec(str);
var todays_date = new Date();
var birth_date = null;

if (res != null) {
    birth_date = new Date(res[1], res[2], res[3]);
    if (todays_date - birth_date > 565633905872) {
```

`565633905872` is `18 years` in milliseconds but how do I convert it to years before so I can just do:

```
if (todays_date - birth_date => 18) {
```

Comment: Hint: there are roughly 31,557,600 seconds in a year.

Comment: _"565633905872 is 18 years in miliseconds"_ - are you sure about that? (That number is too small even if you ignore leap years...)

Comment: Do you really what to compare year using milliseconds?

Comment: @nnnnnn: 565633905872/1000/60/60/24/365 = 17.936something … so it’s not that far off.

Comment: `var x = new Date; x.setSeconds(-565633905872/1000)` would get you the date that is (roughly) 565633905872 before “now”. But if you just want to go 18 years back, `x.setFullYear(x.getFullYear()-18)` is more convenient.

Comment: @CBroe - Yes, it's "only" a couple of weeks off (plus leap days, of which you don't know how many there'll be unless you know the start year). Your `.setFullYear()` method is what I already mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The number you have quoted is *not* the number of milliseconds in 18 years. It's too small even if you pretend there are no leap years.

The simplest way to test if somebody is at least 18 years old is to initialise a date object to their birthday, then use `.getFullYear()` and `.setFullYear()` to directly set the year 18 years forward. Then compare that with the current date.

Note also that in JS dates the month is zero-based, so you probably want to use `res[2] - 1` when creating the date object.

```
birth_date = new Date(res[1], res[2] - 1, res[3]);
birth_date.setFullYear(birth_date.getFullYear() + 18);
if (birth_date <= new Date()) {
```

Or given you are constructing the `birth_date` from individual year, month and day you could just do:

```
birthPlus18 = new Date(+res[1] + 18, res[2] - 1, res[3]);
if (birthPlus18 <= new Date()) {
```

(The leading `+` in `+res[1] + 18` is *not* a typo, it converts the string extracted by your regex into a number so that you can add 18 to it. You don't need to do the same thing for `res[2] - 1` because `-` automatically converts both operands.)

Note also that your regex will happily allow dates that specify a day that is too high for the month, e.g., Feb 30 or Jun 31.

Comment: Yes: that's a lot better

Comment: This great way to check age validity.

Answer (score 8):

There are better ways of checking this (see the answer of "nnnnnn"). But your question wasn't about a better way but, how you could convert to years.

You could write a function that does that, example:

```
function convertmili( mSeconds )
{
    return mSeconds / 31536000000;
}
```

The output of this function is still far from ideal, because your example would output: **17.9361334941654**

So we could clean it up a bit:

```
function convertmili( mSeconds )
{
    var checkYear = Math.floor(mSeconds / 31536000000);
    return checkYear;
}
```

With this function, your example would output **17** and then you can check it the way you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Divide your millisecond value by 31536000000 you get number of years

http://www.convertunits.com/from/milliseconds/to/year

Comment: No you don't. What about leap years?